# How do you translate "to have a hit" in sports?

Tags: traduction, sport

I want to translate the phrase "he invited me to have a hit with him after lunch". However I can't seem to find a non-literal translation of "have a hit" which in this context means to play tennis (could be some other raquet-ball sport) casually. Is there a good translation or would I just have to settle with « il m'a invité à jouer au tennis avec lui après le déjeuner »?

Comment: I added sports to your title because idiomatically the context is key, but feel free to change it to tennis or something more specific.

Comment: *I'm sorry but in English we don't say to have a hit like that*. And I have played tennis. It is not idiomatic English. I expected to see something like a hit song. We do say: Why don't we hit a few balls this afternoon?

Comment: Has anyone asked you to hit a few balls and you find out they are no good. https://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/index.php?threads/has-anyone-asked-you-to-hit-a-few-balls-and-you-find-out-they-are-no-good.240772/

Comment: @Lambie It is certainly  idiomatic in the world of cricket: https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ashes_Diary_2015/aLlpCgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22to+have+a+hit%22&pg=PT118&printsec=frontcover.  "The plan for the morning is to head down to training with the bowlers, and for Bucky and me to have a hit with them.' "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not difficult to conceive that a tennis player would not hesitate to borrow the usual soccer expression "taper la balle", and I believe it would be readily understood.

There is at least this reference to confirm the idea.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Maria_Sharapova_Unstoppable/-ipZDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22taper+la+balle%22&pg=PT14&printsec=frontcover))  toujours adoré taper la balle. Et ce depuis mes quatre ans. C'est la chose qui peut résoudre n'importe quel problème. Vous venez de perdre Wimbledon dans un match frustrant et tout ce qui aurait pu bien tourner a mal viré ?

You can even find this expression shortened to "taper" in this book.[image]

There is term that is longer, but probably less « professional », and that is « échanger quelques balles ».

- Il m'a invité à *échanger quelques balles* avec lui après le déjeuner.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Suzanne_Lenglen_la_Divine/ORQsEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9changer+quelques+balles%22&pg=PT21&printsec=frontcover)) Il s'agissait là d'une véritable garden-party et Suzanne, conviée à échanger quelques balles avec Pierre, le fils du médecin, se trouva rapidement engagée dans une partie mixte

Comment: To have a hit is not an English tennis term. The term is: to hit a few balls.

Comment: taper la balle is to hit the ball and would not mean: to hit a few balls, as in: not play a game or a match.

Comment: @Lambie You think maybe that "Aller taper" means "go to a court play sets"; it is plainly a matter of going to a court and hitting the ball, making returns, without counting faults, or enventually playing sets. If you can say "Aler taper", it is evident that you can as well say "Venez taper" or "Allons taper", etc. // What about "taper la balle" as it is said by soccer players? It is general, not precise :  by tha they meant "playing with the ball" or "having a regular game".  The same "taper la balle" is used in French in the domain of golf.

Comment: Soccer players don't say "taper la balle". The word for a soccer ball is un ballon.

Comment: @Lambie « Neuf tontons qui voulaient taper la balle, et aucun gardien. C'est comme je vous le dis : personne ne veut être gardien. […] La règle : l'équipe qui gagne continue, l'équipe qui perd sort ; chaque partie dure trente minutes. » https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_football_au_Br%C3%A9sil_Onze_histoires_d/xQQtDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22taper+la+balle%22&pg=PT13&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Le ballon de football, normalisé par la Fédération internationale de football association (FIFA), a 32 faces : c'est un polyèdre appelé icosaèdre tronqué. https://kiwix.jackbot.fr/wikipedia_fr_all_maxi_2021-09/A/Ballon_de_football La FIFA gagne ici.

Comment: @Lambie Le terme « ballon » est bien le terme principal, mais il ne faut pas oublier que les commentateurs utilisent le mot « balle » énormément, et que les joueurs l'utilisent aussi. De plus certaines extensions de terme ne sont possibles qu'avec le nom « balle » : « Le gardien dégagea une longue balle vers Pearl qui, à quelques mètres de nous, démarra à la vitesse de l'éclair. ».

Comment: That text you cite is a **literal translation from English**: I have always loved to hit the ball. And it has zero to do with the question. She is not referring to playing informally. She is referring to actually hitting the ball. Geesus.

Comment: to hit the ball in tennis is frapper not taper.

Answer (score 3):

LPH's otherwise good answer states that *taper la balle* is more "professional" than *échanger quelques balles* while in fact, the *taper la balle* is more colloquial and probably better match *to have a hit* so a good translation might be :

***Il m'a invité à taper quelques balles avec lui après le repas.***

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 Oui, bien sûr. C'est cependant pour moi une expression beaucoup plus rare et plus "originale". Elle augure probablement aussi d'un jeu plus agressif.

Comment: Ah, ok, moi j'ai vu _claquer_ dans un truc [québécois](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SWR2EAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA99&dq=%22claquer%20quelques%20balles%22&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q=%22claquer%20quelques%20balles%22&f=false) et la fille allait jouer au mur. Ça sort vraiment peu mais c'est ce que j'aurais dit spontanément mais aussi pour le golf voire le baseball, donc peut-être moins précis que taper. J'en sais très peu sur ces sujets. Ouais le p.s. c'était pour ta préposition devant taper...

Answer (score -3):

To have a hit is not an idiomatic expression for tennis. Have a hit is idiomatic for a toke from a cigarette or a sip from a drink.

to hit a few balls i.e. play without keeping score

> *Quand je parle de “jeu libre”, je veux dire simplement renvoyer la
> balle avec ton partenaire* [to hit balls], au milieu du court, à la
> recherche de contrôle pour offrir une balle confortable, dans une zone
> de frappe facile, lui permettant de te la renvoyer, le tout avec une
> certaine constance. Certains joueurs ne voient pas l’intérêt de jouer
> comme ça, en renvoyant seulement au centre, et trouvent cette façon de
> s’entraîner ennuyante. Ils préfèrent la plupart du temps jouer des
> points ou au moins faire des exercices spécifiques, avec certaines
> situations type, rendant le jeu plus excitant. Oui, c’est certainement
> plus excitant pour leur égo, mais si tu cherches sérieusement à
> t’améliorer sur le long terme, alors tu dois passer un temps
> considérable à travailler ton jeu et ta technique. *C’est ce que permet
> le jeu libre.*

comparer: jouer des points

[Jeu libre](https://tennistempete.fr/jeu-libre/)

Comment: Downvoters: tsk, tsk, tsk. "have a hit" does not exist for playing tennis informally without a match structure. We say: to hit some balls.

Comment: Did you look at the children book title?? [_Let's Have a Hit: Max Plays Tennis_](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Let_s_Have_a_Hit.html?id=r_yOZwEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) Are you saying they're using the expression as an all-purpose expression? You're the native speaker. This author names their book according to the sport they describe ie. _Kick it to me: Jack plays soccer_. I tried to gain access to the book to see if they use the phrase in the text but I can't have access. I find it intriguing.

Comment: Authors strive not be use clichés and **sometimes they fail** This is a great example of that. One hit on a less-than-good title proves nothing. It is very frustrating to have to compete with hits from the internet that cannot properly illustrate meaning.

Comment: Just as I thought. There is a UK edition. Let's have a [bath, game, coffee] is fine. *Let's have a hit*, sounds like marijuana, frankly. Unfortunately, there was no professional editor around to discourage the use of hit in that title.

Comment: Let's have a [x] is British English, very often. But the hit thing does not fly.

Comment: Let's have a hit in baseball would mean: Come on [to the hitter], let's hit the ball. Not at all the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie: Downvoted because a little bit of Googling shows that "have a hit" seems to be perfectly good English in Australia and New Zealand. I can find it used in websites of tennis and ping-pong clubs in Perth and Auckland (but not the U.K. or U.S.).

Comment: Some Aussies also have a campaign: Have a Hit on Us, which is clearly a pun. https://www.manningtennisclub.com.au/haveahitonus In other words, play for free. But in any case, the idea I put in French is correct, and we are not here to correct any English but provide French stuff. In French, jeu libre would mean to play without keeping score.